# Remove second row caused by WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql

I need to remove the 2nd row of results which contain a duplicate of the total record from  the 1st row. My result set is as follows

1 | 1025

1 |  NULL --- I need to remove this row

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT SUM( mdl_quiz.fcpd ) AS cpdtotal, mdl_user.id AS userid
FROM mdl_grade_grades
INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_user.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.id
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz ON mdl_grade_items.itemname = mdl_quiz.name
INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
WHERE mdl_user_info_data.fieldid =1
AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL 
AND mdl_user.annualCPDReportActive =  'Y'
AND (
     mdl_course.category =27
    )
AND mdl_user.id =1025
AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( mdl_grade_grades.timemodified ) ) =2013
GROUP BY mdl_user.id
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `WITH ROLLUP`
more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: I'm so silly.I wrote another query that couldn't calculate without the ROLLUP and now it works,haha.Thank you!